# how to generate minified js file from visual studio code in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I have made a react application using Visual Studio Code. I want to generate a minified js file from Visual Studio Code.
Please suggest me if there is any other option also available for generating minified js file.

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio Code, you can use the minify extension. It works well I'm relying on it for my Javascript.

They're available on the left of your screen, click on the square icon and search for minify.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written your React app with JSX, you need first to transpile the app code into plain JS with Babel. Then you can use [minify VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.minify) on output JS file. Of course, if you didn't use JSX, transpilation is not required.

More convenient option is to setup module bundler (Webpack or Parsel, for example) which will do transpiling and minification automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have have created your app using `create-react-app` command you can execute `npm run build` and it will be available in build directory.

[React build app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build)